# Reformatting a date from YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: javascript, strings, datetime, ecmascript-6, formatting

In this small bit of JavaScript, a date is passed in as `YYYY-MM-DD`. It's formatted like this to be passed to the backend system. On the front end, we need to display it as `MM/DD/YYYY`.

I split the string, and put the each array index in the correct position. However, I feel like there could be a a better way to do this.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
static formatCourseDate(date: string): string {
    const _date = date.split('-');
    const dateObj = {month: _date[1], day: _date[2], year: _date[0]};

    return dateObj.month + '/' + dateObj.day + '/' + dateObj.year;
}
```

Comment: From a high level, are you sure you want to? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Simpler approach

Another option is to construct a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object (this can be achieved by appending a time at midnight to the date) and pass that to [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format). Then there is no need to parse it and reconstruct it yourself.

```js
function formatCourseDate(date) {
  const dateObj = new Date(date + 'T00:00:00');
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(dateObj);
}
console.log(formatCourseDate('1995-12-17'));
```

#### Reviewing your current code

Because this is Code Review and we don't just give alternate approaches, I wanted to also give feedback on the current code.

Given your current approach of splitting the parts of the date:

> ```
> const _date = date.split('-');
> const dateObj = {month: _date[1], day: _date[2], year: _date[0]};
> ```

because [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like `const` are used, [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration) and [the shorthand property definition notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) could also be used to simplify this code:

```js
const date = '2017-11-05';
const [year, month, day] = date.split('-');
const dateObj = {month, day, year};
console.log('dateObj:', dateObj);
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose to use the first option the similar approach that utilizes `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` so I don't have to reconstruct the string and it gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 4):

One cleaner, simpler and more obvious way is:

```
const _date = new Date(date); // yyyy-MM-dd
return (_date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + _date.getDate() + '/' + _date.getFullYear();
```

`getMonth()` - Returns month based on 0 index. So we added 1 to it.

`getYear()` - This is deprecated and `getFullYear()` is recommended. Former returns year as `current year - 1900`. For example, for 2018 it gives 118.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The only problem this that this removed the leading zeros from the months or dates that are less than 10. I could easily check and add a leading zero if needed but then it seems like it would become more jumbled. ....Don't ask why we have to keep the leading zeros. We're just told to do so for *consistency* /s

Comment: You don't have to mess the code by checking single digit numbers. You can use `String.padStart(2, '0')`